# Where does this question belong?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm wondering what the best way to go about porting code from a specific language to another is. I'd like to ask a question about methods, common practice, and tips for porting code from Java to Objective-C.

I am not sure if this question is more appropriate for StackOverflow or Programmers.SE. I *could* ask this as a "tips for porting code" question or from a more technical standpoint.

Which site does this question belong on? Is it wrong to ask twice, once asking for technical info and once asking for generic tips for porting code? Where would the question(s) go?

Comment: +1 for abel's answer. If/when you ask for tips on porting code on Programmers, it'd be great if you could phrase it in a general way ("port from one language to another") instead of the specific Java->ObjC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, for tips and discussion, you can use Programmers.SE. However for specific code issues which you may run into while porting, you should be using Stack Overflow.

**Further Reading:**
https://stackoverflow.com/faq
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: +1, but please don't use SO as code-writing/translating service.